# eventually doesn't attempt second assertion on first failed assertion

Tags: scala, scalatest

Below is a simplified code to understand how eventually works.
But it only attempts assertion once, and eventually doesn't attempts second assertion.

```
package whisk_main

import org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually.eventually
import org.scalatest.concurrent.Waiters.{interval, timeout}
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AsyncFlatSpecLike
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.time.{Millis, Seconds, Span}

class EventuallySpec extends AsyncFlatSpecLike with Matchers{

  "eventually" should "work, as expected" in {

    val runnable = new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        val currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
        println(s"$currentThread starts here")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println(s"$currentThread ends here")
      }
    }

    val threadThatSleepsForFiveSeconds = new Thread(runnable)

    threadThatSleepsForFiveSeconds.start()

    eventually(timeout(Span(15, Seconds)), interval(Span(2, Millis))) {
      println("asserting thread state")
      threadThatSleepsForFiveSeconds.getState should be(Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the exception trace :-

```
Thread[Thread-1,5,main] starts here
asserting thread state





TIMED_WAITING was not equal to TERMINATED
ScalaTestFailureLocation: whisk_main.EventuallySpec at (EventuallySpec.scala:28)
Expected :TERMINATED
Actual   :TIMED_WAITING
<Click to see difference>

org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: TIMED_WAITING was not equal to TERMINATED
    at org.scalatest.matchers.MatchersHelper$.indicateFailure(MatchersHelper.scala:344)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers$ShouldMethodHelperClass.shouldMatcher(Matchers.scala:6778)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers$AnyShouldWrapper.should(Matchers.scala:6822)
    at whisk_main.EventuallySpec.$anonfun$new$2(EventuallySpec.scala:28)
```

---

I tried below example also that is documented on http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html :-

```
val xs = 1 to 125
val it = xs.iterator
eventually { it.next should be (3) }
```

Above example also fails with below example :-

```
1 was not equal to 3
ScalaTestFailureLocation: whisk_main.EventuallyExample at (EventuallyExample.scala:12)
Expected :3
Actual   :1
<Click to see difference>

org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: 1 was not equal to 3
    at org.scalatest.matchers.MatchersHelper$.indicateFailure(MatchersHelper.scala:344)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers$ShouldMethodHelperClass.shouldMatcher(Matchers.scala:6778)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers$AnyShouldWrapper.should(Matchers.scala:6822)
    at whisk_main.EventuallyExample.$anonfun$new$2(EventuallyExample.scala:12)
```

Kindly suggest, why eventually is not working till it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are extending `AsyncFlatSpecLike` while your tests are synchronous. The behaviour you observe, is that `AsyncFlatSpecLike` takes the first Assertion of each of your tests, and fails upon it. Changing the class declaration into:

```
class EventuallySpec extends AnyFlatSpecLike with Matchers {
```

will keep the tests synchronous, and make your tests pass, with the following output:

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] starts here
asserting thread state
asserting thread state
.
.
.
asserting thread state
asserting thread state
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] ends here
asserting thread state
```

as you'd expect.

Another option you have, is using `AsyncFlatSpecLike` if your test is really async. For example the following test passes as well:

```
class MySpec extends AsyncFlatSpecLike with Matchers {

  "eventually" should "work, as expected" in {

    val runnable = new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        val currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
        println(s"$currentThread starts here")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println(s"$currentThread ends here")
      }
    }

    val threadThatSleepsForFiveSeconds = new Thread(runnable)

    threadThatSleepsForFiveSeconds.start()

    eventually(timeout(Span(15, Seconds)), interval(Span(2, Millis))) {
      println("asserting thread state")
      Future {
        Thread.sleep(10)
        threadThatSleepsForFiveSeconds.getState must be(Thread.State.TERMINATED)
      }
    }
  }
}
```